# Is there a non-planar, non-hamiltonian and eulerian graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path

I'm trying to find a graph that is non-planar, non-hamiltonian and eulerian but I can't find anyone.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Take two copies of $K_5$ and identify one of the nodes in one with one of the nodes in the other.

Comment: But K5 is 4-regular. Eulerian graphs has even degrees. If I join two vertex, this will have odd degree.

Comment: @emee: i'm not saying to connect the two vertices with an edge. I'm saying to _combine them into one vertex_. The combined vertex will have degree 8.

Comment: Sorry but I don't undestand. d(v) + d(u) = 2.8 > 5  [Ore's theorem]

Comment: @emee: What is $v$ and $u$? The condition in Ore's theorem talks about pairs of _distinct_ vertices. The graph I describe has eight vertices of degree 4 and one vertex of degree 8, so how do you get $2\cdot 8$ for even one pair of vertices?

Comment: I get it. Thanks so much. I was drawing another graph